# How to play mp3 with FMJ?

Tags: java, mp3

I read in the API, but still not found out how to play a mp3. 
I have not found any tutorials...

Can someone tell me how to use FMJ ? Or give me some tutorial links?

Thank you

Comment: This code works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125934/lineunavailableexception-for-playing-mp3-with-java/3126243#3126243

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure how to play a sound file using Java Sound (avoid Clip(1)), then it is possible to play MP3 files by adding the JMF based [mp3plugin.jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5B9wDXIGw9lRmpSbEUtenljd1k/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-miuzcGB8fsXn2EQh3sVolA) to the run-time class-path of the application.

1. Clip is fine for small sound samples, but is has a limit of just 2 seconds of 16 bit stereo, 44.1 KHz sound, on most Sun JREs.

Comment: @SamySam  "I would not use JMF."  Why not?  And in future, note that more information is better than less.  I should not have to ask you a question as simple and obvious as that one.