# Play mp3 files in java - nullpointerexception

Tags: java, audio

I'm creating an app with some background music. I am trying to play that music with this class:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class SoundPlayer {

    public static void playSound() {
        try{
              AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(SoundPlayer.class.getResource("/Music.mp3"));
             Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
             clip.open(audioInputStream);
             clip.start( );
            }
           catch(Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }

    }
}
```

But I get a nullpointerexception on line 9 which is the AudioInputStream.
I don't know how I can access this file:
[image: Music.mp3]

I tried:

```
SoundPlayer.class.getResource("/Music.mp3")
SoundPlayer.class.getResource("Music/Music.mp3")
SoundPlayer.class.getResource("./Music/Music.mp3")
```

When I put it in the root of my files and use this:

```
SoundPlayer.class.getResource("Music.mp3")
```

I get this error:
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL
**Update**
I tried it to do with JavaFX:

```
package com.audio;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class PlayAudio {

    public static void PlayMP3() {
        Media media = new Media(Paths.get("Music/Music.mp3").toUri().toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        player.play();
    }
}
```

but I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media$_MetadataListener.onMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MetadataParserImpl.done(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.java.ID3MetadataParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MetadataParserImpl.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.audio.PlayAudio.PlayMP3(PlayAudio.java:12)
    at com.Frame1$2.actionPerformed(Frame1.java:61)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
```

The error in on this line: MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media); How can I initialize the toolkit?

Comment: Did you check if your folder and file exist in the .jar-file?

Comment: @YannickRot Yes it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the file in the **root directory**.  Maybe you can access it from there, using `MainClass.getResourceAsStream("file.mp3");`

**EDIT:** Use .wav files.

Comment: I put it in the root and got this error:could not get audio input stream from input URL

Comment: Are you using `getResourceAsStream()`?  That might give you the `InputStream` you need.

Comment: You are also getting an `UnsupportedAudioFileException` .  Have you tried different audio formats?

Comment: No, I didn't try different audio formats, but is there a way to use mp3? That's the most used format in my eyes.

Comment: The getResourceAsStream doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Look at the link I gave you.

Comment: I looked at it, but I can't really get something out of it. I don't understand that. I am not really good with java.

Comment: I would suggest downloading some of the example files there, decompiling them, and looking at the code and jar file structure.

Comment: I don't see any example file?

Comment: Sorry, you should read through this page.  If you still don't get it, read through the entire section.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html

Comment: I am now going to try to do it with JavaFX, but I get Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized

Comment: Initialize the Toolkit variable, I'd assume.

Comment: But how would I do that? I have added the class I am using.

Comment: It's in the main post.

Comment: MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);

Comment: I'll just use wav files for this :P

Comment: You'd think Java would have better APIs for this.

Comment: Yeh, indeed. This sucks a bit.

Comment: Accepted your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125934/lineunavailableexception-for-playing-mp3-with-java/3126243#3126243